# Unknown thread spawns which ignores the filter chain and fails on async decorator

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, asynchronous, amazon-ecs, graphql-java

I am currently facing a strange issue I am not able to reproduce locally, but happens in AWS ECS regularly, letting the application crash or run slow.

We have a spring boot application which extracts the tenant from the incoming GraphQL request and sets the tenant to a `ThreadLocal` instance.

To support `DataLoader` from GraphQL Java kickstart we populate the tenant to each child thread which will be used by the graphql dataloader. The tenant is mandatory to specify the database schema.

**The executor**

```
@Bean
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {

        log.info("Configuring async executor for multi tenancy...");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(15);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("tenant-child-executor-");
        // Important part: Set the MultiTenancyTaskDecorator to populate current tenant to child thread
        executor.setTaskDecorator(new MultiTenancyAsyncTaskDecorator());
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        log.info("Executor configured successfully!");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

**Task Decorator**

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Runnable decorate(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {        
        if (Objects.isNull(CurrentTenantContext.getTenant())) {
            log.warn("Current tenant is null while decorating a new thread!");
        }

        final TenantIdentifier parentThreadTenantIdentifier = Objects.isNull(CurrentTenantContext.getTenant()) ? TenantIdentifier.asSystem() : CurrentTenantContext.getTenant();
        // Also need to get the MDC context map as it is bound to the current local thread
        final Map<String, String> parentContextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        final var requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

        return () -> {
            try {
            
                CurrentTenantContext.setTenant(TenantIdentifier.of(parentThreadTenantIdentifier.getTenantName()));
                if (Objects.isNull(requestAttributes)) {
                    log.warn("RequestAttributes are not available!");
                    log.warn("Running on tenant: {}", parentThreadTenantIdentifier.getTenantName());
                } else {
                    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes, true);
                }

                if (Objects.isNull(parentContextMap)) {
                    log.warn("Parent context map not available!");
                    log.warn("Running on tenant: {}", parentThreadTenantIdentifier.getTenantName());
                } else {
                    MDC.setContextMap(parentContextMap);
                }


                runnable.run();
            } finally {
          
                // Will be executed after thread finished or on exception
                RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
                CurrentTenantContext.clear();
                MDC.clear();
            }
        };
    }
```

**Tenant Context**

```
public class CurrentTenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<TenantIdentifier> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private CurrentTenantContext() {
        // Hide constructor to only provide static functionality
    }

    public static TenantIdentifier getTenant() {
        return currentTenant.get();
    }

    public static String getTenantName() {
        return getTenant().getTenantName();
    }

    public static void setTenant(TenantIdentifier tenant) {
        currentTenant.set(tenant);
    }


    public static void clear() {
        currentTenant.remove();
    }

    public static boolean isTenantSet() {
        return Objects.nonNull(currentTenant.get());
    }
}
```

Locally, this works like a charm. Even in a docker compose environment with limited resources (CPU and Mem) like in AWS. Even 100.000 requests (JMETER) everything works like expected.

On AWS we can easily let the application crash.
After one or two requests, containing some child objects to resolve by GraphQL, we see a thread spawning which seems to ignore or not go through the chain

```
Thread-110 | [sys ] | WARN | MultiTenancyAsyncTaskDecorator | Current tenant is null while decorating a new thread!
```

An interesting thing in this line is the name of the thread.
Each incoming request has the pattern `http-nio-9100-exec-[N]` and each child thread the pattern `tenant-child-executor-[I]` but this one has the pattern `Thread-[Y]`.

Now I am wondering where this thread is coming from and why is it not reproducible locally.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to the problem.

I needed to change

```java
private static final ThreadLocal<TenantIdentifier> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

to

```java
private static final InheritableThreadLocal<TenantIdentifier> currentTenant = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
```

But I don't know why it works with `InheritableThreadLocal` but not with `ThreadLocal` within the AWS environment.

Further, I wonder why this change was not necessary for local testing which works with both ways.

Maybe somebody can provide some ideas.